# Java JFileChooser - I can choose a .txt only in a directory i set

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

Hi im working in a java project and i wanted to create a JFileChooser which i have but i want to choose only in one directory like i have the directory called "Saves" and i want the person who open the JFileChooser can only access txt inside the directory call "Saves". They cant acess anything else only the directory i set.

[I wanted to only access txt and cant acess neither another directorys neither other paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfamM.png)

I researched a lot but i couldn't find anything. If you know about something else like another choose please help me! Thank you.

Comment: what have you tried? [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 5):

A custom [`FileSystemView`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html) can be used to tweak what the user can see and where they can navigate. For example, this is a simple implementation that pretends that the passed-in directory is the root (and home) directory and has no parent (note that the majority of the methods just delegate to the system file system view):

```
public class RestrictedFileSystemView extends FileSystemView {
  private final FileSystemView delegate;
  private final File baseDirectory;

  RestrictedFileSystemView(File baseDirectory) {
    this.baseDirectory = baseDirectory;
    this.delegate = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
  }


  @Override
  public File[] getRoots() {
    return new File[] { baseDirectory };
  }

  @Override
  public File getHomeDirectory() {
    return baseDirectory;
  }

  @Override
  public File getDefaultDirectory() {
    return baseDirectory;
  }

  @Override
  public File getParentDirectory(File dir) {
    if (dir.equals(baseDirectory)) {
      return null;
    }
    return delegate.getParentDirectory(dir);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isRoot(File f) {
    return f.equals(baseDirectory);
  }

  // all methods below here just delegate
  
  @Override
  public Boolean isTraversable(File f) {
    return delegate.isTraversable(f);
  }

  @Override
  public String getSystemDisplayName(File f) {
    return delegate.getSystemDisplayName(f);
  }

  @Override
  public String getSystemTypeDescription(File f) {
    return delegate.getSystemTypeDescription(f);
  }

  @Override
  public Icon getSystemIcon(File f) {
    return delegate.getSystemIcon(f);
  }

  @Override
  public Icon getSystemIcon(File f, int width, int height) {
    return delegate.getSystemIcon(f, width, height);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isParent(File folder, File file) {
    return delegate.isParent(folder, file);
  }

  @Override
  public File getChild(File parent, String fileName) {
    return delegate.getChild(parent, fileName);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isFileSystem(File f) {
    return delegate.isFileSystem(f);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isHiddenFile(File f) {
    return delegate.isHiddenFile(f);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isFileSystemRoot(File dir) {
    return delegate.isFileSystemRoot(dir);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isDrive(File dir) {
    return delegate.isDrive(dir);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isFloppyDrive(File dir) {
    return delegate.isFloppyDrive(dir);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isComputerNode(File dir) {
    return delegate.isComputerNode(dir);
  }

  @Override
  public File createFileObject(File dir, String filename) {
    return delegate.createFileObject(dir, filename);
  }

  @Override
  public File createFileObject(String path) {
    return delegate.createFileObject(path);
  }

  @Override
  public File[] getFiles(File dir, boolean useFileHiding) {
    return delegate.getFiles(dir, useFileHiding);
  }

  @Override
  public File[] getChooserComboBoxFiles() {
    return delegate.getChooserComboBoxFiles();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isLink(File file) {
    return delegate.isLink(file);
  }

  @Override
  public File getLinkLocation(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    return delegate.getLinkLocation(file);
  }

  @Override
  public File createNewFolder(File containingDir) throws IOException {
    return delegate.createNewFolder(containingDir);
  }
}
```

(Only tested quickly on Linux, other OS might require additional changes to some overrides).

Note that you can further restrict what directories the user can visit by overriding `isTraversable()` and even restrict what they see by overriding `getFiles()`.

You can use this custom file system view in your `JFileChooser` like this:

```
FileSystemView fsv = new RestrictedFileSystemView(someBaseDirectory);
JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(fsv);
jfc.showOpenDialog(parentComponent);
```

Comment: nice :) just noticed that the base itself has to be always traversable (otherwise we get an NPE)

Comment: @kleopatra: yeah, `FileSystemView` isn't especially well documented. It almost feels like they just exposed an internal implementation detail. There's certainly a few corner cases that you have to keep in mind and/or find out during testing.

Comment: agree - it very much looks like ad-hoc api ;)

Comment: i did try using your code but didnt work on eclipse... also i really wanted to use JFileChooser... is there any chances to use it?

Comment: First: you need to be more explicit what you mean by "didn't work"? What kind of error message or problematic behaviour did you get? Second: ... this is using `JFileChooser`, I don't know why you keep saying "you want to use it", when this actively makes use of `JFileChooser`. You simply hand it another component to modify how it views the file systsem (a file-system-view if you like).